# Adding Strings in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I am in my IOS application in which i am getting ID from server which i am saving in string and then add strings in NSMutableArray.I am not getting perfect method by which i can add the strings in array and use the array outside the scope.
Here is my code Please help me out::

```
- (void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary
{
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    i=0;
    NSLog(@"%s %@ %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, inRequest.sessionInfo, inResponseDictionary);
    if (inRequest.sessionInfo == kUploadImageStep)
    {
        snapPictureDescriptionLabel.text = @"Setting properties...";
        NSLog(@"%@", inResponseDictionary);

     NSString* photoID =[[inResponseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"photoid"] textContent];
     flickrRequest.sessionInfo = kSetImagePropertiesStep;

// for uploading pics on flickr we call this method
  [flickrRequest callAPIMethodWithPOST:@"flickr.photos.setMeta" arguments:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:photoID, @"photo_id", @"PicBackMan", @"title", @"Uploaded from my iPhone/iPod Touch", @"description", nil]];
   [self.array addObject:photoID];
    arr=array[0];
    counterflicker++;
     NSLog(@"  Count : %lu", (unsigned long)[array count]);

}
```

How can i add the photoID(Strings) in the array?
Please help me out..

Comment: What precisely is the problem?

Comment: Why are you use self.array ? Only  write like this. [array addObject:photoID];

Comment: if you want to use the `array` in a parent scope, probably you have to define the `array` in the parent scope. does is make sense to you?

Comment: are you sure you got a photoID ?

Comment: yes i am getting photoID,but when i am adding the strings in array,every time it adds object but all objects contains same value.

Comment: now this is an other issue!! this will depends on request which was you send on server, whatever you get from there it will be add in array, so please check request that you send on server.

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't compile.  Can you tidy it up please?

Answer (score 1):

for adding **NSString** in **NSMutableArray** is like this

```
NSString *str = @"object";
NSMutableArray *loArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[loArr addObject:str];
```

In your code Why are you using **self.array** ? just write like this. **[array addObject:photoID]**;

Comment: why are you copy my answer ?

Comment: i am not copy ur ans . see my ans carefully. please

Answer (score 0):

I observe that in your code. you declare mutable array in local scope.

So just use

```
 [array addObject:photoID];

Instead of 

   [self.array addObject:photoID];
```

May be you are create property for this array with same name, then you need to alloc it.

If you create a property for this then remove local declaration and alloc array like this.

```
 self.array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and then use

```
   [self.array addObject:photoID];
```

Comment: I am already making property for this array,and also declare this in .h file,,but i am unable to add strings in the array?

Answer (score 0):

- self keyword is used for global variables but here in your code
  "array" is a local variable .So need of self.array

> [array addObject:photoID];

- Before adding check that photoID is nil or not

> ```
>  if (photoID.length > 0) {
>         [array addObject:photoID];
>     }
> ```